# How do i make that when the timer count back it will refresh/update the text from the text file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

In my code i have a text file on my site i read it line by line and display it on a jquery plugin newsTicker.
Also  i have a timer count back in this case 4 minutes back i don't display the timer but it count back.

I want that when the counter/timer get to 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds it will refresh somehow the page on my website or somehow to refresh maybe the text file reading part so it will display the new content of the text file.

I have a program i did in c# that update the text file content every 4 minutes and then upload it to my website.
So first time for example the text file content is: Hello World and my website display Hello World.
Then after 4 minutes the text file content is: This is a test 
Now i want it to display in the jquery plugin: This is a test

Then the timer should start counter over again 4 minutes back for some reason now the timer stop at 0 0 0 .

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<style>
.newsticker {
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: auto;
}

.newsticker li {
    color: #4e4e4e;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #2c8162;
}

.newsticker li:hover {
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
<script language='JavaScript'>
   var count = 300;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;
    //document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + //" Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update."; // //watch for spelling
    }
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test1.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i+=1) {  // step: 3
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
                //$ul.append('<li>' + lines[i+1] + '</li>');
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 5,
                speed: 600,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
</script>
<br><br><span id="timer"></span><br><br>
```

Comment: Olirav the ticker i think. I don't want the visitors in my site to see every 4 minutes the text get clear or something like that. I want it to be smooth keep scrolling as it is now and if there is new content it will just get in and will scroll with the other lines that already scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a timer. Look at the setTimeout function : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
    function updateTicker() {
        $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
        var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test1.txt";
        $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i+=1) {  // step: 3
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
                //$ul.append('<li>' + lines[i+1] + '</li>');
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 5,
                speed: 600,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
        });

        // 4 minutes in millisecondes
        setTimeout(updateTicker, 240000);
    }
    updateTicker();
</script>
```

Comment: ArGh it's working. But is there anyway to avoid this clearing after 10 seconds i mean each 10 seconds the whole text is disappearing for second. Maybe there is way to update it without this disappearing ? It looks like it's blinking every 10 seconds i changed it for 10 seconds to check the updating for testing. Also each 4 minutes it will disappear like that.

Comment: Somehow i want to replace or remvoe this line: $('body').find('.newsticker').remove(); this line every 10 seconds or 4 minutes will clear all the text from the jquery newsTicker if it's 10 seconds it will look like it's flashing also 4 minutes it will clear it all that's not nice. Is there anyway instead clear it all just to push each time the new text so it will just get into the scrolling loop and replace old text that already exist ? Something like that.

Comment: To remove the $('body').find('.newsticker').remove(); you have to modify the script generating the test1.txt as follow :
1) make it in json format
2) use date
3) in your javascript function make date comparaison to add only new line

Comment: example : [{"timestamp":1399446201,"text":"My news 1"},{"date":timestamp,"text":"My news 2"}]. For each execution of the updateTicker, you save the last timestamp so you can identify new lines at the next execution.

Comment: ArGh could you show me please the complete solution somerime maybe ? I don't know even yet how to make json format the text file. I tried to ask there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511338/how-do-i-save-a-text-content-as-json-format-file-name-on-my-hard-disk

Comment: In php there is a function json_encode. You pass an array as argument and it output a json array. To have hebrew working, you need to convert you data in UTF-8 (utf8_encode in PHP). I'm not a C programmer but I'm pretty sure you can find some equivalent.

Comment: ArGh just to make clear sorry. For example if i pass in the json_encode let's say array with two lines from my text file as it is now it will return this two lines as json format ?

Comment: yes. You have to make an array with all you entry and apply the json_encode on the array. You obtain a json array you just have to put in your text file.