# How do i save a text content as json format file name on my hard disk?

Tags: c#, json

This is the code i'm using now to create text files on my hard disk:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\test1.txt", false))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\test.txt"))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        var strReadLine = sr.ReadLine().Trim().Replace("\t", "").Replace("\r\n", "");
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strReadLine))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(strReadLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

In the end test1.txt content format look like this:

[Text](http://justpaste.it/fd4c)

It's in hebrew. But the format is one line of text file then under it line of date and time. And so on.
For example:

```
Hi world
דווח במקור בתאריך: 07.05.14  שעה : 09:56
Hello all
דווח במקור בתאריך: 07.05.14  שעה : 09:54
Hi everyone
דווח במקור בתאריך: 06.05.14  שעה : 23:09
```

I want to save on my hard disk not only as text file but also to save this ocntent as json format file.
strReadLine is string variable once it contain text line and once date and time line.

Comment: Tried to add this line in the loop: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new { strReadLine = strReadLine}); but i'm getting error: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'

Answer (score 0):

To output to JSON, you should first arrange your data using the structure that you wish to store. You can achieve this by creating a concrete class (or even a dynamic type) containing the properties that you wish to store. Then you can use a library such as Json.Net to serialize your objects. See http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm as a start - the docs are pretty good.

As for reading / writing files, I'd recommend using `File.ReadAllLines()` or `File.ReadLines()` (depending on your scenario - check out [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a comparison of the two). For output, File.WriteAllLines() works well.